# need to add string in between a SQL statement using TCL

Tags: sql, tcl

I have a SQL statement stored inside a variable:

I get this "statement" from the ".sql" file using file operations

```
set statement "SELECT build_package,
replace(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(substring(build_package, length(build_package) - position('/' in reverse(build_package)) + 2), '-BSD',''),'-LNX',''),'-esxi',''),'.repo',''),'.vmdk',''),'.qcow2',''),'.rpm',''),'.tbz',''),'-version',''),'.el7.x86_64','') ,'-NR',''),'-kvm',''),'-x86_64',''),'ptsvpl','svpts'),'spbvpl','svspb'),'sdevpl','svsde'),'-amd64',''),'.noarch',''),'.el6',''),'.x86_64',''),'tsevpl','svtse')
FROM scheduler_jobs WHERE id = '1617075' order by id DESC"
```

here the where clause is e.g.: `WHERE id = 1617075` the id is dynamically generated.

So I need to first store the *sql* without `WHERE id = 1617075` clause and add the where clause later when i get it inside the 'statement' variable.

Basically add some data called  `$id`  in the *statement*.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [prepared statement](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TdbcCmd/tdbc_statement.htm) with bound variables.

The example from the documentation:

```
set statement [db prepare {
    select phone_num from directory
    where first_name = :firstname and last_name = :lastname
}]
set firstname Fred
set lastname Flintstone
```

As the documentation explains,

> The **prepare** object command against the connection accepts arbitrary SQL code to be executed against the database. The SQL code may contain *bound variables*, which are strings of alphanumeric characters or underscores (the first character of the string may not be numeric), prefixed with a colon (**:**). If a bound variable appears in the SQL statement, and is not in a string set off by single or double quotes, nor in a comment introduced by **--**, it becomes a value that is substituted when the statement is executed. A bound variable becomes a single value (string or numeric) in the resulting statement.
>   *Drivers are responsible for ensuring that the mechanism for binding variables prevents SQL injection.*

In other words, while it *is* the driver's responsibility, you should be protected against SQL Injection. In other words, if the `id` isn't simply `1617075` but rather [`1617075; DROP TABLE scheduler_jobs;--`](https://xkcd.com/327/), you should still be okay, because the driver has properly escaped this (instead of *you* having to do this, missing an edge case which leaves you vulnerable).

---

For your example, leaving out all the `REPLACE`s, this would become

```
set statement [db prepare {
    SELECT build_package 
    FROM scheduler_jobs
    WHERE id = :scheduler_job_id
    ORDER BY id DESC
}]
set scheduler_job_id 1617075
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use *string map*.

First save your string as a template with a tag in it and remove any part you want to substitute:

```
set statement "SELECT build_package,
replace(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(substring(build_package, length(build_package) - position('/' in reverse(build_package)) + 2), '-BSD',''),'-LNX',''),'-esxi',''),'.repo',''),'.vmdk',''),'.qcow2',''),'.rpm',''),'.tbz',''),'-version',''),'.el7.x86_64','') ,'-NR',''),'-kvm',''),'-x86_64',''),'ptsvpl','svpts'),'spbvpl','svspb'),'sdevpl','svsde'),'-amd64',''),'.noarch',''),'.el6',''),'.x86_64',''),'tsevpl','svtse')
FROM scheduler_jobs <WHERE_CLAUSE> order by id DESC"
```

Here the tag I choose is , but you could use what you prefer.

And then:

```
set query_cmd [string map {<WHERE_CLAUSE> "WHERE id = '123456'"} $statement]

puts $query_cmd
```

This could be done for many different part of the string you need to change, just use another tag.

```
set query_cmd [string map {<TAG1> $v1 <TAG2> $v2...}  $statement]
```

You can of course put inside the string a quoted variable like:

```
...WHERE id = '\$id'...
```

And then use *subst*, but I think in this case the *string map* could be more useful.